# CSS Positioning - Fill whitespace from floated elements

Tags: html, css

How do I go about positioning Box4 so that is pushed up against Box1?

[image]

Looking forward to your suggestions and any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="align.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <section class="boxes">
        <b>BOX1</b>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, nihil excepturi laudantium ipsum! Voluptate ducimus velit voluptatibus, molestias modi quia dignissimos sint dolorum quasi nemo asperiores sit reiciendis ipsam, neque?
    </section>
    <section class="boxes">
    <b>BOX2</b>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, nihil excepturi laudantium ipsum! Voluptate ducimus velit voluptatibus, molestias modi quia dignissimos sint dolorum quasi nemo asperiores sit reiciendis ipsam, neque?
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, nihil excepturi laudantium ipsum! Voluptate ducimus velit voluptatibus, molestias modi quia dignissimos sint dolorum quasi nemo asperiores sit reiciendis ipsam, neque?
    </section>
    <section class="boxes">
    <b>BOX3</b>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, nihil excepturi laudantium ipsum! Voluptate ducimus velit voluptatibus, molestias modi quia dignissimos sint dolorum quasi nemo asperiores sit reiciendis ipsam, neque?
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, nihil excepturi laudantium ipsum! Voluptate ducimus velit voluptatibus, molestias modi quia dignissimos sint dolorum quasi nemo asperiores sit reiciendis ipsam, neque?
    </section>
    <section class="boxes">
    <b>BOX4</b>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, nihil excepturi laudantium ipsum! Voluptate ducimus velit voluptatibus, molestias modi quia dignissimos sint dolorum quasi nemo asperiores sit reiciendis ipsam, neque?
    </section>
    <section class="boxes">
    <b>BOX5</b>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, nihil excepturi laudantium ipsum! Voluptate ducimus velit voluptatibus, molestias modi quia dignissimos sint dolorum quasi nemo asperiores sit reiciendis ipsam, neque?
    </section>
</div>
```

```
.boxes {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you divide it in 3 rows vertically and place in there the elements, or you have to absolute position them with some math which is quite hard. but no worries, there is a great plugin [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) that handles it for you.

Good luck!